# Advice on the learning resources for deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Which is better for beginner in machine learning: The deep learning book written by Yoshua Bengio or the videos and notes in CS231n from Stanford?

Comment: First take the course (don't just read the notes) _then_ buy the book if you can afford it. If not it is free online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/
- http://www.deeplearningbook.org/

They are the two very popular online free books. The first link even has working deep learning code.